# How to download only the selected records using checkbox in classic/IR report@oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

How to download only the selected records using the checkbox in classic/IR report at Oracle apex and I created a button Export in below report region.

Env:
Oracle 12c
Oracle apex 18.1

So can u please suggest on this.

Comment: This is not the right place for such questions. You would probably easily find the answer to this question in the help forums for this software.

Comment: Note that custom solutions like this may not be so simple and that approaches can vary significantly. Classic Reports and IRs are very different. Please narrow your question down by picking one or the other.